# JS Cookie path not setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, js-cookie

I am using the following Javascript API for setting a cookie:

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

I am trying to set the path to the current page, but it is setting to the root. My code to set the cookie is:

```
Cookies.set('timeElapsed', data.seconds, {path: ''});
```

Which is part of a wider function which is tracking the progress of a Vimeo video, so I can use the cookie to resume from the last play point when the page is returned to.

But the cookie that is being set has the path `/`, meaning I can't use the same code for other videos on the site.

How can I set the cookie for just the current page?

Answer (score 0):

just remove the path attribute

```
document.cookie="timeElapsed="+data.seconds;
```

**UPDATE**

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yxhgnaj8/)

[image]

Comment: That sets the path to `/`, which is a site-wide cookie. I need it to be page-specific to the current page

Comment: @MikeHarrison are you sure that it sets it to '/' ? cause i'm pretty sure it doesn't. please have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/yxhgnaj8/ have a loog to the cookies in Resources tab

Comment: @MikeHarrison please have a look for the image in the updates answer

Comment: The difference is he's using js-cookie, you aren't. Yes, that makes a difference, because js-cookie uses '/' path as default.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. By default [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) creates the cookie valid to all pages inside `/` path. If you want to make it available to the **path** of the current page (not **the** current page), then you use the code:

```
Cookies.set('timeElapsed', data.seconds, {path: ''});
```

Basically, in [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), `path: ''` is the same as `document.cookie='name=value'`. If no attribute is declared, then it assumes `document.cookie='name=value; Path: /'` by default.